# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"14"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in ......on line 11

Tags: php, sql

I have a code like this but it gives me error

```
 include_once 'wp-config.php';
    $number = 14 ;
    $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $number 14 ); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
 $id = $row["ID"];
 $title = $row["post_title"];
 $content = $row["post_content"];
```

My blog is wp so any clue to slove this

Thank you

Comment: no closing quotes after 14

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the end double quote in your MYSQL query. Should be :

```
    $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $number 14 ");
```

However, this is still going to have another bug as `LIMIT $number 14` is garbage.

- Do you want to limit by 14 or $number?
- is $number an offset?  if so you'd want  `LIMIT $number, 14`

I'm guessing by the rest of your code you just want to limit by number and the addition of 14 to the queryis a mistake.  So use:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $number ");
```

Comment: $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $number ");  this but error is now Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'lekalic'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in & Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established & Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in what to do now? any solutions

Comment: Now the code is syntactically correct, but you've got a credential issue with your DB connection.  You should created another post asking about help resolving this.

Comment: I try to creat another post but i cant creat new for several days! I dont know how to slove this cause site is fine and only get topic is not working any help thank you!